# I am having difficulty to write this formula in the LaTeX form

Tags: sqrt

[image]

I am having difficulty writing this formula in the LaTeX form. I am not familiar with LaTeX. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Should it be an inline formula or a displayed one?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually inline mode formula you can do this with the engine `pdfLaTeX`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$M_{S}=k\ast \overline{r_{\mathrm{cf}}}\,/\sqrt{k+k(k-1)\overline{r_{\mathrm{ff}}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
$M_{S}=k\ast \overline{r_{cf}}\,/\sqrt{k+k(k-1)\overline{r_{ff}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

But being your formula build with the font `Cambria Math` of Office-Word I suggest to use `LuaLaTeX` engine:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\begin{document}
$M_{S}=k\ast \overline{r_{cf}}\,/\sqrt{k+k(k-1)\overline{r_{ff}}}$
\end{document}
```

....and you will get this that is very closer to your image.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

By use of the `nicefrac` package and more standard way of writing math expressions:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141502]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}
$M_{S} = \nicefrac{k \overline{r_{\mathrm{cf}}}}
                  {\sqrt{k+k(k-1)\overline{r_{\mathrm{ff}}}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]